# Load document ready script from child control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I put javascript in a child control and expect it to execute on document load?
My child control renders HTML correctly however the javascript is not rendered to the page and of course does not execute.  Is it possible to do what I am asking and if so what am I doing wrong?

In my parent .cshtml page I have:

```
@Html.Action("LoadToolsControl", "ToolsControl", new { area="Common" })
```

ToolsControl.cshtml looks like this:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:190px;">
    <ul id="ToolsControlToolsList"></ul>
</div>
@section scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hi there');
    });
</script>
}
```

The bottom few lines of my LayoutPage look like this:

```
      @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout page doesn't really "interact" this way with the child action. Think of it like an independent subpage that is inserted into the parent. Specifying the @section scripts in the child won't work with @RenderSection in the parent.

Try to use Partial instead of child action or tell us a little bit more about why you are doing it like this.

Comment: The child control is hosted by several different parent pages.  I need to pass a viewmodel to the child control when I load hence the call to the controller.  Note @RenderSection is specified in the Shared _Layout page.

Comment: In that case you can simply ignore the whole @section/@RenderSection logic and output the javascript code directly. Or you can add the "@section" declaration under your RenderAction call if you insist on keeping your scripts at the end... Simply said, "@RenderSection" in parent is not aware of anything you declare in the child. You need to choose a different pattern. But that is out of scope of this question.